# How to create dynamic dataframe using python loop?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a 4 dataframes that I generate for 2 products each, totaling 8 dataframes.

Currently, I create each dataframe manually such as (very clunky):

```
productA = productA.withColumn('col1', productA['col2'] / productA['col3'])
productA = productA.withColumn('col4', productA['col5'] / productA['col6'])
productA = productA.withColumn('col7', productA['col8'] / productA['col9'])
productA = productA.withColumn('col10', productA['col11'] / productA['col12'])

productB = productB.withColumn('col1', productB['col2'] / productB['col3'])
productB = productB.withColumn('col4', productB['col5'] / productB['col6'])
productB = productB.withColumn('col7', productB['col8'] / productB['col9'])
productB = productB.withColumn('col10', productB['col11'] / productB['col12'])
```

I am trying to make the code lighter by trying to do something like this:

```
product=['productA','productB']

for i in product:
    df_i = df_i.withColumn('col1', df_i['col2'] / df_i['col3'])
    df_i = df_i.withColumn('col4', df_i['col5'] / df_i['col6'])
    df_i = df_i.withColumn('col7', df_i['col8'] / df_i['col9'])
    df_i = df_i.withColumn('col10', df_i['col11'] / df_i['col12'])
```

Is this achievable given that also dataframe suffixed should be created? When I run such code, it does not work.

Comment: The `i` in `df_i` is not a suffix and will not get the value of the variable `i`. It is simply a string so all the dataframes you create in the loop have the same name and thus overwrite another.

Comment: @JanWilamowski Do you have a good way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def cal_new_column(df):
    for i in range (1, 11, 3):
        numerator = i+1
        denominator = i+2
        df = df.withColumn(f'col{i}', col(f'col{numerator}') / col(f'col{denominator}'))
    
    return df


df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
(2, 4, 8, 16, 10, 20, 33, 66),
(1, 2, 3,  6,  2,  8, 11, 22),
],['col2', 'col3', 'col5', 'col6', 'col8', 'col9', 'col11', 'col12'])

productA = cal_new_column(df)
productB = cal_new_column(df)

productA.show(10, False)
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
# |col2|col3|col5|col6|col8|col9|col11|col12|col1|col4|col7|col10|
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
# |2   |4   |8   |16  |10  |20  |33   |66   |0.5 |0.5 |0.5 |0.5  |
# |1   |2   |3   |6   |2   |8   |11   |22   |0.5 |0.5 |0.25|0.5  |
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+

productB.show(10, False)
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
# |col2|col3|col5|col6|col8|col9|col11|col12|col1|col4|col7|col10|
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
# |2   |4   |8   |16  |10  |20  |33   |66   |0.5 |0.5 |0.5 |0.5  |
# |1   |2   |3   |6   |2   |8   |11   |22   |0.5 |0.5 |0.25|0.5  |
# +----+----+----+----+----+----+-----+-----+----+----+----+-----+
```